# Verification of a double integral with absolute value $\iint_{X} \frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2} \ dxdy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification, multiple-integral

I wanted to evaluate the following integral,

$$I=\iint_{X} \frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2} \ dxdy$$
with ${X}=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq1, x^2+y^2\leq2|x|\}$.

I used polar coordinates, setting $x=r\cos(\theta), \ y=r\sin(\theta)$, but I'm concerned about how to express the condition $x^2+y^2\leq2|x|$, which turns into $r/2 \leq |cos(\theta)|$, now since $r\in[0,1]$, it should be $cos(\theta) \in [1/2, 1]$, namely $\theta\in[-\pi/3, \pi/3]\cup[2\pi/3, 4\pi/3]$ so we end up evaluating 2 double integrals, the first one with theta in $[-\pi/3, \pi/3]$, the latter with theta in $[2\pi/3, 4\pi/3]$. Is my reasoning correct?   [image]

Comment: Mikasa's answer is correct. Try to show that the area Mikasa has highlighted is $X$.

Comment: I'm not getting it. Look at the picture I posted, the intersection between the red-delimited area and the blue circles is not the one proposed by Mikasa

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates
\begin{align}
&\iint_X \frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}dxdy
=4 \iint_{X,x>0, y>0}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}dxdy\\
=& \ 4\bigg( \int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_0^1 +\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\bigg) \cos \theta \sin\theta \ rdr d\theta
=  \frac34 + \frac18=\frac78
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to evaluate the integral in the region $x,y\ge0$, $(x,y)$ being an element in the intersection

- of the unit disk (centered in the origin), this is delimited by the red circle in the posted picture,
- with the disk centered in $(1,0)$ of radius one, this is the right blue disk   from the posted picture.

We further separate this region in two parts, separated by the vertical line of equation $x=1/2$. So let us compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac I4
&=
\iint_{\substack{(x,y)\in X\\ x,y\ge 0}}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\; dx\; dy
\\
&=
\int_0^{1/2}dx
\int_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\; dy
+
\int_{1/2}^1 dx
\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\; dy
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^{1/2}dx
\Big[x\log(x^2+y^2)\ \Big]_0^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}
+
\int_{1/2}^1 dx
\Big[x\log(x^2+y^2)\ \Big]_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^{1/2}x\Big(\log(x^2+(2x-x^2)) -\log x^2\Big)\; dx
\\
&\qquad\qquad 
+
\frac 12
\int_{1/2}^1 x\Big(\log(x^2+(1-x^2))-\log x^2\Big)\; dx
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^{1/2}x\log(2x)\; dx 
-
\frac 12
\int_0^1 x\log x^2\; dx
\\
&=
\frac 12
\left[
\frac 12 x^2\log(2x) - \frac14x^2
\right]_0^{1/2}x\; dx 
-
\frac 12
\left[
\frac 12 x^2\log(x^2) - \frac12 x^2
\right]_0^1 
\\
&=
-\frac 1{32} + \frac 14=\frac{32}{8-1}=\frac7{32}\ .
\\[2mm]
&\qquad\text{ Alternatively, we can use Fubini the other way around:}
\\[2mm]
\frac I4
&=
\iint_{\substack{(x,y)\in X\\ x,y\ge 0}}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\; dx\; dy
\\
&=
\int_0^{\sqrt 3/2}dy
\int_{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\; dx
\\
&=
\frac12
\int_0^{\sqrt 3/2}y\; dy\; 
\Big[\ \log(x^2+y^2)\ \Big]
_{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
\\
&=
\frac12
\int_0^{\sqrt 3/2}y\; dy\; 
\Big[\ \log\Big((1-y^2)+y^2\Big) - \log\Big(\Big(1-\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)^2 + y^2\Big)\ \Big]
\\
&=
-
\frac12
\int_0^{\sqrt 3/2}y\; dy\; 
\log\Big(\Big(1-\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)^2+y^2\Big)
\\
&=
-
\frac12
\int_0^{\sqrt 3/2}y\; dy\; 
\log\Big(2-2\sqrt{1-y^2}\Big)
=
-
\frac14
\int_0^{3/4} 
\log\Big(2-2\sqrt{1-t}\Big)\; dt
\\
&=
-
\frac14 
\Big[\ t\log\Big(2-2\sqrt{1-t}\Big)\ \Big]_0^{3/4}
+
\frac14
\int_0^{3/4} 
t\cdot\frac 1{2-2\sqrt{1-t}}\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt{1-t}}\; dt =\dots
\\
&=\frac7{32}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
At the last step use $(2-2\sqrt{1-t})
(2+2\sqrt{1-t})=4-4(1-t)=4t$. We obtain:
$$
I = \frac 78\ .
$$